# old version of node running - source /usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh

Tags: node.js

when I do node -v I get:

```
 ~ node -v
v0.12.4
```

When I comment out the line in ~/.bash_profile

```
source /usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh
```

it goes to version 6.2.2 (which is what I want), however then gulp doesn't work.

I'm hoping I can get some help as to how to get nvm.sh to run the current version of node. Should I reinstall nvm (if so what is the proper way) or...?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using `nvm` for node.js versioning. In order to properly change the version is alias is as the default version like so:

`nvm alias default v6.2.2`

this will set the default node version to 6.2.2 and you probably could restart the terminal for the env variables to be updates as well